# React-navigation undefined Error

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, expo

I have an interesting question: So I import this

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Feed')} style={styles.buttonContainer}>
   <Text  style={styles.buttonText}>
        LOGIN
   </Text>                 
</TouchableOpacity>
```

button from a form I created,
I import it to a screen that I want to load the form on like this:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding' style={styles.container}>

              <View style={styles.logo}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 64, color: '#34B3E4'}}>Partner<Text style={{fontSize: 64, color: '#0077B5'}}>Up</Text></Text>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 13, opacity: 0.8, color: '#0077B5'}}>We connect you. You work easier.</Text>
              </View>
              <LoginForm/>           <-------------------Here is the import
              <View style={styles.accountLogin}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Forgot')}>
                        <Text style={{opacity: 0.9,color:'#34B3E4'}} >Forgot your password? </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>  
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

but my onpress function to transition screens doesnt want to relay and throws an undefined error
Cant import something and render an onpress function anywhere even in my router:

```
Feed: {
     screen: Feed,
     navigationOptions: {
       title: 'Mentor',
       header:{
         right: //Going to be the users profile picture
       <Icon  
       onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}
       name="user" 
       color='#0077B5'
       size={30}
        />,
        left: //Messages
       <Icon  
       name="message" 
       color='#0077B5'
       size={30}
        />,
       titleStyle: { color: '#0077B5' },
      }
     }
   },
```

what do i have to do exactly

[Here be the logcat error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYOI7.jpg)

Comment: Is there a logcat for the undefined error? If so, Include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the properties to your child component to

Change

```
<LoginForm/>
```

to

```
<LoginForm navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
```

For it to work in navigator, use a reference

```
<Navigator
 ref='navigator'
 ...
/>
```

and then

```
<Icon
  navigator={this.refs.navigator}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped me fix my error! What about when I am using that onpress function in my router? How can I pass the properties along to that specific icon? Throws a similar error.